# URL call with string keyword substitution

Tags: python, parsing, url, urllib2

```
import urllib2
from xml.dom import minidom

query = """http://phx01.companyA.com:8000/?query=kindle+fire&country_id=1&lang_id=1&linkin_id=8073631&sbh_id=120555,1&weight_group_id=80&request_id=p20.b6894b85df2f81d54003&brand_id
=14623&request_type=SRS&............."""    #multiple lines, a lot content omitted

response = urllib2.urlopen("".join(query.split('\n')))
dom = minidom.parse(response)
```

The above sample query went though (I replaced the real company name by `companyA` in the above link).

Now if I want to replace `kindle fire` by `iphone5`, how to make it?
I thought I can make it something like

```
keyword = "iphone5"
"""...... query = %s.............""" %(keyword)
```

but it failed, I suspect it might have something to do with keyword encode, but how to do this here?

Comment: As a side note, to avoid having that long line and while still having a correct code, you could split `query` by doing something like

`query = """http://phx01.companyA.com:8000/""" + \ """?query=kindle+fire&country_id=1&""" + \ ...` 

or

`query = ("""http://phx01.companyA.com:8000/""" """?query=kindle+fire&country_id=1&""" ...)`

with each item on a separate line. For more details see this [paste](https://gist.github.com/ciupicri/302b77943436031ff040).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a placeholder `{query}` and fill it out using [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting):

```
import urllib

query = """http://phx01.companyA.com:8000/?query={query}&country_id=1&lang_id=1&linkin_id=8073631&sbh_id=120555,1&weight_group_id=80&request_id=p20.b6894b85df2f81d54003&brand_id=14623&request_type=SRS"""

value = "kindle fire"
query = query.format(query=urllib.quote_plus(value))
```

Note that you would need to encode the value with [`urllib.quote_plus()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus). Here's what it does:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> value = "kindle fire"
>>> urllib.quote_plus(value)
'kindle+fire'
```

---

Alternatively, you can make a dictionary of query parameters and [`urlencode()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) it afterwards:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> value = "kindle fire"
>>> params = {'query': value, 'country_id': '1'}
>>> urllib.urlencode(params)
'query=kindle+fire&country_id=1'
```

You can even parse the url using [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html), get the query parameters using [`parse_qsl()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qsl), set the appropriate `query` parameter value and `urlencode()` parameters:

```
>>> url = """http://phx01.companyA.com:8000/?query=kindle+fire&country_id=1&lang_id=1&linkin_id=8073631&sbh_id=120555,1&weight_group_id=80&request_id=p20.b6894b85df2f81d54003"""
>>> params = urlparse.urlparse(url).query                                                                                                                     
>>> params = urlparse.parse_qsl(params)
>>> params
[('query', 'kindle fire'), ('country_id', '1'), ('lang_id', '1'), ('linkin_id', '8073631'), ('sbh_id', '120555,1'), ('weight_group_id', '80'), ('request_id', 'p20.b6894b85df2f81d54003')]
>>> params = dict(params)
>>> urllib.urlencode(params)  
'linkin_id=8073631&country_id=1&lang_id=1&weight_group_id=80&request_id=p20.b6894b85df2f81d54003&query=kindle+fire&sbh_id=120555%2C1'
>>> params['query'] = 'iphone'
>>> urllib.urlencode(params)
'linkin_id=8073631&country_id=1&lang_id=1&weight_group_id=80&request_id=p20.b6894b85df2f81d54003&query=iphone&sbh_id=120555%2C1'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used urllib.quote_plus(), it worked.